# Почему в python нельзя определить дескриптор как атрибут экземпляра класса

Tags: python

Ниже я определил класс дескриптора. А также класс, при инициализации объектов которого создается поле с экземпляром дескриптора:

```
class Descriptor:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print('get is called')

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print('set is called')

class My_Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = Descriptor()
```

После создания экземпляра класса My_Class. И при обращении к атрибуту 'x' я ожидаю вызов метода `__get__` дескриптора. Также не отрабатывает и `__set__`:

```
    my_obj = My_Class()
    print(my_obj.x)
```

Атрибут `my_obj.x` содержит в себе экземпляр Descriptor.
`<__main__.Descriptor object at 0x7f4cc3f7b860>`

Comment: ```my_obj.__dict__['x'].t = 2

    print(my_obj.__dict__['x'].__dict__['t'])
```
Ни __get__ ни __set__ не вызвался.

Comment: Вы по сути возвращаете атрибуты экземпляра дескриптора,  а не запускаете методы ```__get__``` и ```__set__```. Если бы они отрабатывали как надо, должны были запуститься соответствующие принты геттера и сеттера.